# How to customize chip style when my app theme inherit from "Theme.AppCompat"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-chips

I want to use the android widget "[ChipGroup & Chip](https://velmm.com/material-chips-material-components-for-android/)" in my app which are from android material 'com.google.android.material', but I am using like principle theme for My App "Theme.AppCompat" so when I try to custom the style for each of theme I always get a crash saying:

> This component requires that you specify a valid TextAppearance attribute. Update your app theme to inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).

How should I proceed?

Comment: You have to use a [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) Theme or a [Bridge](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#bridge-themes-bridge-themes) theme

Comment: I can not do that (the style parent is fixed, it is not up to me)

Comment: You can only try to add all [these attributes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#appcompat-themes-app-compat-themes) in the app theme (again you have to change it). No other way.